# How can I use if statement for a button. I mean when the user click on a button a certain code will run.

Tags: asp-classic

How can I use if statement for a button. I mean when the user click on a button a certain code will run. 
Is it something like this ? 
If 'name'(of the button) = 'value' (of the button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've tagged this as classic asp - I assume what you are trying to do is check if a form has been submitted.  First you give your button a name - eg

```
<input name="sendbutton" value="send" type="submit">
```

Then in the asp file to which you are posting the form you could use something like

```
If request("sendbutton") = "Send" then
 Response.write "Thank you for registering"
Else
 Response.write "Please enter your details"
End If
```